# R : data.table subsetting based on a integer column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Just wondering if there is a slicker way to subset a data.table. Basically I have a big table with millionish rows and hundreds cols. I want to subset it based on an integer col/s having a value between a range defined by me.

I was wondering if the set the relevant column as the Key it would be binary search but then not sure if I can find the rows between a range of values.

Contrived example below.

```
> n = 1e7
> dt <- data.table(a=rnorm(n),b=sample(letters,replace=T,n))
> system.time(subset(dt, a > 1 & a < 2))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.596   0.000   1.596
> system.time(dt[a %between% c(1,2)])
   user  system elapsed 
  1.168   0.000   1.168
```

can something like this be done?

```
setkey(dt,a)
dt[  ] : get me the rows between 1 and 2 values of the key
```

Thanks!
-Abhi

Comment: `between` will not save any time because it contains the code `x >= lower & x <= upper`. `dt[a > 1 & a < 2]` will be just as fast

Comment: how about using setting a key ? I just updated my question not sure I can do a ranged search on a key.

Answer (score 8):

If you *do* set the key on `a` (which will take some time (14.7 seconds on my  machine for `n=1e7`),
 then you can use rolling joins to identify the start and end of your region of interest.

```
# thus the following will work. 
dt[seq.int(dt[.(1),.I,roll=-1]$.I, dt[.(2), .I, roll=1]$.I)]


n = 1e7
dt <- data.table(a=rnorm(n),b=sample(letters,replace=T,n))
system.time(setkey(dt,a))
#  This  does take some time
# user  system elapsed 
# 14.72    0.00   14.73
library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function() t1 <- dt[floor(a) == 1]
f2 <-  function() t2 <- dt[a >= 1 & a <= 2]
f3 <- function() {t3 <- dt[seq.int(dt[.(1),.I,roll=-1]$.I, dt[.(2), .I, roll=1]$.I)]   }
microbenchmark(f1(),f2(),f3(), times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  f1() 371.62161 387.81815 394.92153 403.52299 489.61508    10
#  f2() 529.62952 536.23727 544.74470 631.55594 634.92275    10
#  f3()  65.58094  66.34703  67.04747  75.89296  89.10182    10
```

It is now "fast", but because we spent time earlier setting the key.

Adding @eddi's approach for benchmarking

```
 f4 <- function(tolerance = 1e-7){  # adjust according to your needs
  start = dt[J(1 + tolerance), .I[1], roll = -Inf]$V1
  end   = dt[J(2 - tolerance), .I[.N], roll = Inf]$V1
 if (start <= end) dt[start:end]}
 microbenchmark(f1(),f2(),f3(),f4(), times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#  f1() 373.3313 391.07479 440.07025 488.54020 491.48141    10
#  f2() 523.2319 530.11218 533.57844 536.67767 629.53779    10
#  f3()  65.6238  65.71617  66.09967  66.56768  83.27646    10
#  f4()  65.8511  66.26432  66.62096  83.86476  87.01092    10
```

Eddi's approach is slightly safer as it takes care of floating point tolerance.

Answer (score 7):

Doing a `setkey` here would be costly (even if you were to use the fast ordering in `1.8.11`), because it has to move the data (by reference) as well.

However, you can get around this case by using `floor` function. Basically, if you want all the numbers in [1,2] (Note: inclusive of 1 and 2 here), then `floor` will provide a value of "1" for all these values. That is, you can do:

```
system.time(t1 <- dt[floor(a) == 1])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.234   0.001   0.238
```

This is equivalent to doing `dt[a >= 1 & a <=2]` and is twice as fast.

```
system.time(t2 <- dt[a >= 1 & a <= 2])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.518   0.081   0.601 

identical(t1,t2) # [1] TRUE
```

However, since you don't want the equality, you can use a hack to subtract the tolerance = `.Machine$double.eps^0.5` from column `a`. If the value is in the range `[1, 1+tolerance)`, then it's still considered to be 1. And if it's just more, then it's not 1 anymore (internally). That is, it's the smallest number > 1 that the machine can identify as not 1. So, if you subtract 'a' by tolerance all numbers that are internally represented as "1" will become < 1 and `floor(.)` will result in 0. So, you'll get the range > 1 and < 2 instead. That is,

```
dt[floor(a-.Machine$double.eps^0.5)==1]
```

will give the equivalent result as `dt[a>1 & a<2]`.

---

If you've to do this repetitively, then probably creating a new column with this `floor` function and setting key on that `integer` column could help:

```
dt[, fa := as.integer(floor(a-.Machine$double.eps^0.5))]
system.time(setkey(dt, fa)) # v1.8.11
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.852   0.158   1.043
```

Now, you can query whatever range you want using binary search:

```
> system.time(dt[J(1L)])    # equivalent to > 1 & < 2
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.071   0.002   0.076 
> system.time(dt[J(1:4)])   # equivalent to > 1 & < 5
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.082   0.002   0.085
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a key set, then your data is sorted, so just find the endpoints and take the points in between:

```
setkey(dt, a)
tolerance = 1e-7  # adjust according to your needs
start = dt[J(1 + tolerance), .I[1], roll = -Inf]$V1
end   = dt[J(2 - tolerance), .I[.N], roll = Inf]$V1
if (start <= end) dt[start:end]
```

This will be a little bit slower than Arun's `floor` approach, since it does 2 joins, but on the plus side you can plug in any numbers you like.

Comment: given that the rolling joins will only produce a single return value, you can avoid the `[1]` `[.N]` subsetting.

Comment: I was sure `roll` will roll out sooner or later :)

Comment: @mnel that's actually not the case, try `data.table(a = c(1,1,1), key = 'a')[J(1), roll = Inf]`

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point. (I'd prefer consistency myself in the so that all records which "Match" as defined by roll (i.e. roll = -1 etc), which would avoid the two calls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `data.table` expert, but from what I understand the reason a `key` search `setkey(dt, b) ; dt['a']` is so fast is because it uses binary search instead of vector scan. That's not possible for numeric columns where subsetting **requires binary operators**.

The only alternative would be to do something like:

```
dt[,Between:=ifelse(a > 1 & a < 2, 'yes', 'no')]
setkey(dt, Between)
> system.time(dt['yes'])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.04    0.00    0.03
```

Which, interestingly, is faster even than:

```
Index = dt[,a > 1 & a < 2]
> system.time(dt[Index])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.23    0.00    0.23
```

But since you can just save a subset as a separate data.table anyway, I don't see this having much application.